# Convert string to time and calculate difference

Tags: java, time

I have two strings : `1.20.2` and `1.23.0`

They are minutes, i.e. `1.20.2` stands for 1 minute 20.2 seconds.

How can I convert these strings into time values and then do a subtraction?

For example:

```
1.23.0 - 1.20.2 = 0.2.8
```

Comment: 20.2 seconds = 20 secs 200 millisecs? or 20 secs 2 millisecs?

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), its a very good API for date/time operations. Otherwise you have to reinvent the wheel...

In my opinion the name of the classes and functions of the API are very intuitional

This is the code (**successfully tested!**):

```
PeriodFormatter pf = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
.printZeroAlways() // print zero minutes
.appendMinutes()
.appendSeparator(".")
.appendSecondsWithMillis()
.toFormatter();

Period p1 = pf.parsePeriod("1.20.2");
Period p2 = pf.parsePeriod("1.23.0");

Period diff = p2.minus(p1);
System.out.println(diff.toString(pf));

// output:
// 0.2.800
```

Comment: What about "Convert string to time"?

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot. Now I edit my answer, should be complete now @JustYo

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `SimpleDateFormat`, like this:

```
    String min1 = "1.20.2";
    String min2 = "1.23.0";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("m.ss.S");

    Date parse = sdf.parse(min1);
    Date parse2 = sdf.parse(min2);

    long diff = parse2.getTime() - parse.getTime();
    Date date = new Date(diff);
    String format = sdf.format(date);
    System.out.println(format);
```

This will print `0.02.998`. To get your expected result of `0.2.8` you have to pass `1.20.200` as `min2` as this is how the SimpleDateFormat interprets this value.

Comment: and you get the answer as `30.02.998` (when you convert the long back to date) and not 0.2.8 as the OP wants

Comment: With the example above I get `30.02.998`. Anyway `0.02.998` is not what the OP wants

Comment: @Nivas: Hm you are right the correct input for `min1` has to be `1.20.200`. `1.20.2` is interpreted as `1.20.002`. Maybe it is acceptable for the OP, else here a conversion is necessary.

Comment: @Nivas and @user714965 try the updated code now i have added sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Answer (score 1):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert them to `Date` objects. Then use `Date.getTime()` to get the "milliseconds since epoch", compute the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Is the time always in the same format? If so, you can use the `split(String regex)` method, for example:

```
String time1 = "1.20.2";
String[] splitTime1 = time1.split(",");
```

This will give you a string array. I don't know how important it is that you convert them into a DateTime - personally I would convert each item in the array to an int of the same units, for example:

```
int secondsTime1;
secondsTime1 = (splitTime1[0] * 60) + (splitTime1[1]) + (splitTime1[2] * Math.pow(10, -3));

//Assume you do the same with the second time to get secondsTime2;

int difference = secondsTime1 - secondsTime2;
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be easy, have you attempted to solve this yourself?

Anyway, pseudo code will look like

```
For each string
    pos = string.indexOf(".")
    Split string into two parts min, sec based on the index "pos"
    stringSecs = min*60 + sec

Find difference of stringSecs by regular subtraction.

Convert back to required format using min = answer/60, sec=answer%60
```